# XOR of two SHA-256 Hash

Tags: hash, sha256, xor

I am looking for converting following two hash values generated from `SHA-256` bit hash.

```
hash1="8bb0cf6eb9b17d0f7d22b456f121257dc1254e1f01665370476383ea776df414" //SHA-256 bit hash of 1234567
hash2="fe68a21fc76bba7b3a3d8e454eca8cd258de68fd08dddf035f23ddbdce6fc049" //SHA-256 bit hash of 7654321
```

Is it possible to have `xorhash=hash1^hash2`?
`xorhash=75d86d717edac774471f3a13bfeba9af99fb26e209bb8c7318405e57b902345d` is the output.
Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us, together with a description of your problems with it.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @David - It is the xor of two hash values.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Any approach?

Comment: @Mayuresh What about the xor of two hash values? And what does your question have to do with C? Are you trying to write C code to do something? If so, what? To perform SHA256 hashing? Do you literally want text output? What library are you using or planning to use?

Comment: @surajs1n - I have tried python code, which works accuractly

Comment: >>> print hex(int("8bb0cf6eb9b17d0f7d22b456f121257dc1254e1f01665370476383ea776df414", 16) ^ int("fe68a21fc76bba7b3a3d8e454eca8cd258de68fd08dddf035f23ddbdce6fc049", 16))
0x75d86d717edac774471f3a13bfeba9af99fb26e209bb8c7318405e57b902345dL

Comment: @David- It is for my interest to be performed on IoT device, in pure c. I am just using standard library's for now.

Comment: You state your intention to  do something vaguely described. You give two values. You ask about possibility to perform a certain operation, without describing any problem you have with it. Then you describe an output. Then you ask for help. With what? What I read is "I am looking to convert to numbers. Number1= 5, Number2=7. Is it possible to have AddNumber=Number1 + Number2 ? AddNum = 13. Please help." Do you see what I mean? It is not possible to answer to something like that. Please explain more about the obstacles you encounter. What is special about the three numbers you show?

Comment: However, after consulting my magic ball, it comes up with "The XOR of two hashes is not, and is not supposed to be, the hash of the XOR of the two hashed inputs. Any operation with that characteristic would not be described as a hash." Is that helpful to you?

Comment: @Mayuresh So is your question how to do a SHA256 in pure C? Is that the step you're stuck on?

Comment: @David - Thank you for your concern. It was just about combining two SHA-256 bit hash by xor in C. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want you have 2 options:

**a) Keep everything as strings**

In this case you'd want a "for each character" loop that converts the source characters from `char` to an integer, does the XOR, then converts the result back into a `char`. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256/4; i++) {
    d1 = hash1[i];
    if( (d1 >= '0') && (d1 <= '9') ) {
        d1 = d1 - '0';
    } else if( ( (d1 >= 'A') && (d1 <= 'F') ) || ( (d1 >= 'a') && (d1 <= 'f') ) ) {
        d1 = d1 - 'A' + 10;
    } else {
        /* Syntax error */
    }
    d2 = hash2[i];
    if( (d2 >= '0') && (d2 <= '9') ) {
        d2 = d2 - '0';
    } else if( ( (d2 >= 'A') && (d2 <= 'F') ) || ( (d2 >= 'a') && (d2 <= 'f') ) ) {
        d2 = d2 - 'A' + 10;
    } else {
        /* Syntax error */
    }
    dr = d1 ^ d2;
    if(dr < 10) {
        dr = dr + '0';
    } else {
        dr = dr - 10 + 'A';
    }
    result[i] = dr;
}
```

**b) Use integers**

As you can see strings are slow and messy, and they also waste RAM (and put more pressure on caches, etc).

If you used integers instead, then C doesn't support 256 bit integers so you need to break it up into whatever C does support. For example:

```
struct myHash {
    uint32_t digit[256/32];
}

struct myHash hash1 = { 0x8bb0cf6e, 0xb9b17d0f, 0x7d22b456, 0xf121257d, 0xc1254e1f, 0x01665370, 0x476383ea, 0x776df414 };
```

In this case you can do:

```
for(i = 0; i < 256/32; i++) {
    result[i] = hash1[i] ^ hash2[i];
}
```

Note that this is doing significantly less work inside the loop, and there's a lot less iterations of the loop (8 iterations doing 32 bits at a time instead of 64 iterations doing 4 bits at a time).

In fact; the compiler may convert this into "loopless" code, like this:

```
result[0] = hash1[0] ^ hash2[0];
result[1] = hash1[1] ^ hash2[1];
result[2] = hash1[2] ^ hash2[2];
result[3] = hash1[3] ^ hash2[3];
result[4] = hash1[4] ^ hash2[4];
result[5] = hash1[5] ^ hash2[5];
result[6] = hash1[6] ^ hash2[6];
result[7] = hash1[7] ^ hash2[7];
```

..and (for some computers) it might convert it into SIMD (e.g. if the computer supports 256 bit operations with AVX2, then this could become 3 instructions even though C doesn't support 256 bit integers).